# Batch Script to get a IPV4 address of a computer then if the IP is within a range run a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to get this batch file to work. there are 2 ip ranges that need to be checked upon.

10.0.50.xxx
10.0.60.xxx

so far, I've done this with no avail.

[rolled back to original - OP has also experimented with `*` in the matching string]

```
     ipconfig | find /i "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.50." >nul 2>nul && (

  call script.bat 

) || (

  ipconfig | find /i "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.6." >nul 2>nul && (

  call script2.bat 

) || (

exit
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You do realise that there's a `0` missing from `60` in your code, don't you? What happens if you simply run the 2 lines `ipconfig|find...&&call script?.bat` or perhaps in place of `&&` `if not errorlevel 1 `?

Comment: I added the " * " to the end of ip address since this value is variable. the output comes as More?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this suitable?

```bat
IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.50.">Nul 2>&1 && (Call script.bat) || (
    IPConfig|FindStr/IRC:"IPv4 .*: 10.0.60.">Nul 2>&1 && Call script2.bat)
```

*I'm afraid it is untested*

Comment: Awesome! Yes, it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much